# Divide the bibliography into 3 sections with different labels and ordered according to the order of call

Tags: biblatex

I would like to divide my bibliography into three sections depending on the type of my source (articles, internet and others). I had no problem for this step and with the code I have that you can see:

[image]
[image]

I get a structure as you can see on the left side of the next picture (right side is what I need):

[image]

However, I'd like to set a different logic for the "labels" (what's between the brackets) for each bibliographic section, and get something like on the right part of the previous image.

For example, for the "articles" section I would like to sort them in order: [A1], [A2], [A3]...
Internet section: [I1], [I2] [I3] and "Others": [O1], [O2], [O3]

Similarly, I would like the references in the bibliography to be sorted according to the order in which I cite them in my text. I would like the first article I cite in my text to be [A1], the second article to be [A2], the first internet reference to be [I1].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For future questions please keep in mind that images of code are quite hard to handle: People who want to experiment with your code need to re-type all of it, images can also be hard to read or pose a severe accessibility issue for people with screenreaders. It is usually a much better idea to just copy and paste the code as text.

Comment: Yes I didn't thought about it but it is logical ! Thank you and sorry, I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

The prefixes can be added to the labels with `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=<prefix>]` before the respective `\printbibliography`. (`labelprefix` requires `defernumbers` as a global option.)

Note that there is no need to define a bibfilter for the *other* bibliography, we can just combine `nottype`s. We can also do away with the `\addcontentsline`s if we just use `heading=bibintoc,` and `heading=subbibintoc`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,markey,ctan,aksin}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibintoc, title=Articles]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=I]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibintoc, title=Internet]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=O]
\printbibliography[nottype=article, nottype=online, heading=subbibintoc, title=Other references]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography with different prefixes.]

---

If you want to sort the citations as well, you need the option `sortcites` and a few tweaks to the sorting template

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none-pre, sortcites, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none-pre}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {A}]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {I}]
    }
    \map{
      \pernottype{article}
      \pernottype{online}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {O}]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I could use `A`, `I`, `O` for the `presort` values here, since they have the expected order if sorted alphabetically. If you want a different order or need additional prefixes, you can choose different strings for the `presort` fields.

If `\DeclareSortingTemplate` throws an undefined control sequence error, you must be using an outdated `biblatex` version (at most v3.7 from 2016-12-08), the command used to be called `\DeclareSortingScheme`, so try replacing

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{none-pre}{
```

with

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{none-pre}{
```

in the code above. (But there could be other issues with such an old version.)